# Fetching data's using  indexed column vs MySQL range criteria  which is best?

Tags: mysql

TABLE  User
User Table Structure .

```
    mysql> desc User;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| EMAIL_ID     | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| IP_ADDRESS   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CREATED_TIME | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This table contains million's of rows and it will be gradually increasing on day by day .

Goal :

```
To getting past 12 month's user details from this table .
```

First get a user id was created before 12 month's . My query look like this .

Option 1:

```
Select * from User where ID > `Account created before 12 months` .
```

Option 2:

```
Select * from User where CREATED_TIME > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`2011-01-2011 00:00:00`)*1000;
```

Which is efficient for fetching details . And this query will be used redudantly for audit purpose  .

Comment: Do you have a question (other than just what's in the title)?

Comment: what problem is it that you face?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid calling functions on each row. You can write your first part of the WHERE clause like this to speed up a lot (especially if you couple it with an index on the CREATED_TIME field):

```
Accounts.CREATED_TIME
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000 + 999
```

Note that this will make the function calls only once and indices on the CREATED_TIME field can be used to resolve the query.

Comment: Thanks Emil for your quick response .
Actual Query.
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000, 'SIGNIN', 0, count(distinct(zuid)) as SIGN_IN_COUNT from Accounts where date_format(from_unixtime(Accounts.CREATED_TIME/1000),'%Y-%m-%d') = CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 1 DAY and operation = 'SIGN_IN';
+---+---------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000 | SIGNIN | 0 | SIGN_IN_COUNT |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------

|                                           1334514600000 | SIGNIN | 0 |           299 |

Comment: I optimized my query based on your instructions it returns wrong result . I posted my actual response in my previous comment .

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000, 'SIGNIN', 0, count(distinct(zuid)) as SIGN_IN_COUNT from Accounts where Accounts.CREATED_TIME BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000 + 999;

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000 | SIGNIN | 0 | SIGN_IN_COUNT |

|                                           1334514600000 | SIGNIN | 0 |             0 |

Comment: Thanks a lot

I Found answer from your instructions